# Why when I use multiprocessing it spend more time?

Tags: python

The code I use without multiprocessing is as below, it time it spend is 0:00:03.044280:

```
def execute_it():

    number = 10000000
    listing_1 = range(number)
    listing_2 = range(number)
    listing_3 = range(number)
    start = datetime.now()
    task(listing_1, listing_2, listing_3)
    print datetime.now() - start

def task(listing_1, listing_2, listing_3):

    for l1, l2, l3 in zip(listing_1, listing_2, listing_3):
        l1 + l2 + l3
```

I want to use multiprocessing to spend less time, the code I tried is as below:

```
def execute_it():


    number = 10000000
    listing_1 = list(range(number))
    listing_2 = list(range(number))
    listing_3 = list(range(number))

    params = zip(listing_1, listing_2, listing_3)


    start = datetime.now()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=5)
    pool.map(task, params)
    pool.close()
    print datetime.now() - start

def task(params):

    params[0] + params[1] + params[2]
```

it spend 0:00:15.654919 !!!

What is wrong in my code? I am sure the thing they do is same.

Comment: You can profile it to confirm it, but I think `params = zip(listing_1, listing_2, listing_3)` + creating 5 processes is what makes it take longer than the single-process version. Try itertools.izip

Comment: @khachik I tried it, it even spent more time:0:00:18.134695

Comment: please see my answer for the details

Comment: @khachik many thanks for your help. it do work when it is a fucntion, but when I use it in the class(especially task in class), it just ignore the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiprocessing version takes longer because it is effectively the same as the single-process version plus some additional stuff like creating processes and running map.

You can replace zip with `itertools.izip` and `mp.map` with `mp.imap` to get the expected parallelism effect, otherwise all the heavy processing will happen in the main process.

```
from itertools import izip
...

def execute_it():
    number = 10000000
    listing_1 = list(range(number))
    listing_2 = list(range(number))
    listing_3 = list(range(number))

    params = izip(listing_1, listing_2, listing_3)

    start = datetime.now()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=5)
    pool.imap(task, params)
    pool.close()
    print datetime.now() - start
```

Comment: it works for me, only spend 0:00:01.126610. And I have one more question, can imap used in class function?

Comment: @YuchenHuang not sure I understand the question - if you mean classmethod then yes, method scopes are irrelevant here.

Comment: I mean when I use self.task in the class, this code doesnt work

Comment: @YuchenHuang your original post does not contain anything about your classes and methods and it is hard to tell what is going on without seeing the code. You can ask a separate question since it is completely unrelated to mp performance.